# Show $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n{n-1\choose k-1} =2^{n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics

- **Given** $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k{n\choose k} = n\cdot 2^{n-1}$$

---

- **I know that** $$k\cdot{n\choose k}=n\cdot{n-1\choose k-1}=(n-k+1)\cdot{n\choose k-1}$$

  Therefore $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k{n\choose k} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n n{n-1\choose k-1} = n\cdot 2^{n-1}$$

  So, $$n\cdot\sum\limits_{k=1}^n {n-1\choose k-1} = n\cdot 2^{n-1}$$

  Therefore $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n{n-1\choose k-1} =2^{n-1}$$

---

**How is $\quad\sum\limits_{k=1}^n{n-1\choose k-1} =2^{n-1}\quad$?**

Comment: You know that $\quad\sum\limits_{k=0}^n{n\choose k} =2^{n}\quad?$

Comment: Just get new variables that are one less than your old ones, and use Exodd's hint.

Comment: @Exodd I understand now, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With $j=k-1$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n {n-1\choose k-1}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose j}=2^{n-1} $$

Answer (score 2):

$$2^{n-1}=(1+1)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}\cdot 1^{n-1-k}\cdot 1^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k-1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\sum_{k\ =\ 1}^{n}{n - 1 \choose k - 1} = 2^{n-1}:\ {\large ?}}$

> With $\ds{a > 1}$:

\begin{align}
&\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{k\ =\ 1}^{n}{n - 1 \choose k - 1}}
=\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{n - 1 \choose k - 1}
=\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\bracks{%
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a}{\pars{1 + z}^{n - 1} \over z^{k}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}
\\[5mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a}\pars{1 + z}^{n - 1}
\bracks{\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\pars{1 \over z}^{k}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a}\pars{1 + z}^{n - 1}
\bracks{{1 \over 1 - 1/z}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a}{z\pars{1 + z}^{n - 1} \over z - 1}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=2\pi\ic\lim_{z\ \to\ 1}\bracks{\pars{z - 1}{z\pars{1 + z}^{n - 1} \over z - 1}
\,{1 \over 2\pi\ic}}
=\color{#66f}{\LARGE 2^{n - 1}}
\end{align}

Comment: What kind of mathematics are you doing here, I don't know any of that?

Comment: @KermittheHermit This is a 'standard' use of 'contour integrals' which is a quite useful 'tool'. Study this example very careful and you'll have another method in your pocket. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Combinatorially we can prove this simply by noting that both the lefthand side and the righthand side count subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ all containing a fixed element, $1$.